# Double pointer to binary search-tree node

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, double-pointer

This might seem like a silly question to some of you and I know that I get things mixed up quite often but I need to understand the code so I can stop obsessing about it and focus on the real matter of why I need to use it.

So, in the code I see several assignments like this:

```
struct bst_node** node = root;
node = &(*node)->left;
node = &(*node)->right;

is there an invisible parenthesis here?

node = &((*node)->right);
```

This example is taken from literateprograms.org.

So to me it seems &(*node) is unnecessary and I might as well just write node->left instead, but the code seems to work where I can't make sense of it and I'm wondering if it's because I'm misunderstanding what's happening at those lines. Particularly, at one place in the code where it is deleting a node by constantly moving the "deleted" data to the bottom of the tree to safely remove the node without having to "break things", I'm lost because I don't get how

```
old_node = *node;
if ((*node)->left == NULL) {
    *node = (*node)->right;
    free_node(old_node);
else if ((*node)->right == NULL) {
    *node = (*node)->left;
    free_node(old_node);
} else {
    struct bst_node **pred = &(*node)->left;
    while ((*pred)->right != NULL) {
        pred = &(*pred)->right;
    }
    psudo-code: swap values of *pred and *node when the 
    bottom-right of the left tree of old_node has been found.
    recursive call with pred;
}
```

can keep the tree structure intact. I don't understand how this makes sure the structure is intact and would appreciate some help from somebody who knows what's going on. I interpret node being a local variable on the stack, created at the function call. Since it is a double pointer it points to a location in the stack (I assume this, since they did &(*node) previously to the function call), of either it's own stack or the function before, which then points to said node on the heap.

In the example code above what I think it is supposed to do is switch either left or right, since one of them is NULL, and then switch the one that isn't (assuming the other one isn't NULL?) As I said, I'm not sure about how this would work. My question mostly relates to the fact that I think &(*node) <=> node but I want to know if that's not the case etc.

Comment: Yes there is a hidden parenthesis, sorry I wrote that before your edit

Comment: @dzada it's fine! I forgot so it's fair game ;) But I still don't understand the variables. See other comment

Comment: It is all about precedence `->` binds tighter than `&` or `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `node = &(*node)->right;`
>
> is there an invisible parenthesis here?
>
> `node = &((*node)->right);`

Yes. It is taking the address of the `right` member of `*node`. The `->` takes precedence over `&`; see [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) (`->` is 2 and `&` is 3 in that list) (it's the same general precedence as C).

> So to me it seems &(*node) is unnecessary and I might as well just write node->left instead,

Your premise is off. There is no expression `&(*node)`, as explained above, the `&` applies to the entire `(*node)->left`, not `(*node)`.

In that code the double pointers are just that, a pointer to a pointer. Just as this works:

```
   int x = 0;
   int *xptr = &x;
   *xptr = 5;
   assert(x == 5);
```

This is the same, it changes the value of the pointer x:

```
   int someint;
   int *x = &someint;
   int **xptr = &x; 
   *xptr = NULL;
   assert(x == NULL);
```

In that code snippet you posted, assigning a pointer to `*node` changes the value of the pointer that `node` points to. So, e.g. (pseudo-ish code):

```
   typedef struct bst_node_ {
     struct bst_node_ *left;
     struct bst_node_ *right;
   } bst_node;

   bst_node * construct_node () {
     return a pointer to a new bst_node;
   }

   void create_node (bst_node ** destination_ptr) {
     *destination_ptr = construct_node();
   }

   void somewhere () {
     bst_node *n = construct_node();
     create_node(&n->left);  // after this, n->left points to a new node
     create_node(&n->right); // after this, n->right points to a new node
   }
```

Noting again that `&n->left` is the same as `&(n->left)` because of precedence rules. I hope that helps.

In C++ you can pass arguments to a function by reference, which is essentially the same as passing a pointer except syntactically it leads to code that is a bit easier to read.

Comment: So, in your &n->left, for example, you get a pointer to the exact memory location within the node n, where it has it's left pointer, and then in create_node assigns a new node to it?

It's just so typical by the way that just as I post something I see the answer. If you saw my comments on the other guy's post, I kind of realised after this. So typical... haha

Comment: Yes exactly. If you were to subtract the memory address `(&n)` (parens for clarity) from `&n->left`, the result would be the offset of the `left` member into a `bst_node` structure -- that'd most likely be 0 in my example.

Comment: Try this: `printf("%i %i\n", (char*)&n->left - (char*)&n, (char *)&n->right - (char *)&n);`

Comment: That's quite useful, I think. Anyway, the whole purpose of the assignment is to make it multi-threaded and I just wasn't sure how it worked so I didn't know when and where to lock etc. Print could be useful. Anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

That is useful

`&(*node)->left` <=>`&((*node)->left)`

The variable edited by this code is `*node`. I need the context fo this code to give more info

Comment: But how does that edit the parent node's pointer to point to the left one? What happens under the hood at that last part? Because to me, it seems it is only editing stack variables and not infact the node (on the heap)

Comment: It is written in pseudo code, the `pred` will browse the left branch of the `old_node` tree to the bottom right leaf, then swap this leaf with `node`. To give more details I would need the context of this code (function call maybe). Basically here in the code you pase it edits `*node` which is not defined in the code you gave, so maybe not on the stack.

Comment: Seeing since the while loop will do that, in the recursive call (which again i forgot to write in) will in the next run be at a place where the right side is NULL, and it will just check once again if it has a left side, then basically goes into free_node which deletes one of them..

I think I kind of figured out why it works now, but I'm just not sure. I'm so confused :D haha

Comment: Yes because at the end, if if finds that `(*pred)->right` is null, then if the left is null `old_node` gets freed, and research continues on right branch. if left != null as right is null (because of the previous while) then old_node is freed and research continue on left